# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am currently working with Nodejs. When i was call a function from another file it show the following error

```
error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

This is function where i called from another file

```
exports.signupconfirm = function(req,res) {
        var id                  = req.params.id;
        var obj_id      = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);

        logger.log('info','FILE ['+__filename.split('/').pop()+'] : LINE ['+stackTrace.get()[0].getLineNumber()+'] : Signup Confirm ID: '+id);
        logger.log('info','FILE ['+__filename.split('/').pop()+'] : LINE ['+stackTrace.get()[0].getLineNumber()+'] : Signup Confirm ObjectID: '+obj_id);
        dbconnection.Ucollection.find({"_id":obj_id}).toArray(function(err,result) {
                if(err)logger.log('info','FILE ['+__filename.split('/').pop()+'] : LINE ['+stackTrace.get()[0].getLineNumber()+'] : Check the Database Connection details from SIGNUPCONFIRM');
                var confirm     = result[0].confirmation;
```

}

Comment: Post the code what you have tried..

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the relevant code.  That is pretty much ALWAYS the case here on stack overflow.  If you're asking a question about your code, you must show the relevant portions of your code.  It should tell you exactly what line of your code the error is on.  We need to see the code at that line and before that line.

Comment: You probably applying a function to var you haven't define. 
Please post your code

Comment: Please provide your code ! without that we cannt help beecuase this error can be thrown for diffrent causes.

Comment: Locate the line with 'params'. Should be used as an 'someObject'.params where your 'someObject' is undefined. Check why it is undefined

Comment: Please provide a full code snippet of where you actually use signupconfirm

Comment: req.params is the params of your route. the route is something like `/api/signup/:id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.params` always refers to the variables in your route path.

If you don't pass any id parameter, it will be undefined (like in your case).

Like @chenkehxx mentioned here, you need to pass the id through the route.
Suppose it's `/api/signup/:id` than `/api/signup/1` will fetch the id of 1 and then `req.params` will return 1 and not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about your project but you can go in a different way of passing it by a object pointer like this:

```
    exports.ObjectName = ObjectName;
```

should fix the error.